# What is the difference between 没有 vs 了没有in sentence?

Tags: grammar

Is there any difference the following sentences? They seem the same to me:

你吃饭没有?

vs

你吃饭了没有?

Comment: sentences made up by user or is there another source for them?

Comment: Questions on the function of 了 had been asked many many time. https://chinese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E4%BA%86

Comment: the common structure is "你吃了饭没?" (have you eaten yet?)

Comment: ＠user6０６５  can find many examples of alternative questions ending in ＂了没有＂ or "V了O没有＂ in the case of 离合词 V+O，but it seems not so many of type ＂V没有", here is one: 看见没有: 黑猫: 看见没有? 乌云计划会顺利地进行下去的.  For alt.q. ending in  吃饭没有 did not find any on 1st 2 pages of web search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 你吃饭没有?
>
> 你吃饭了没有?

You are correct! Both are natural and mean the same thing.

You could also say 你吃饭没?, 吃饭没？， 吃饭了没？, 吃完饭没？，... Those colloquial sentences are used in daily life.

Answer (score 0):

In these two sentences the meaning are the same. But“了没有” is not a commonly used phrase. “了” is a word which is used for making the sentence more convenient to speak out orally. “了” itself has no real particular meaning in many sentences    ,including this one. But it can also translated as a past tense. Also in this sentence.